# Ansible: Is there any way to use or pass ansible vars to a bash script I am deploying?

Tags: bash, ansible, pam

I am hacking together an Ansible solution to deploy a notify.sh bash script as part of a pam.d / pam_exec configuration.

The script uses a bunch of variables that I have been told need to be a part of a separate yml file (so others can change or update them) instead of being defined in the script directly, which is what I am normally used to doing.

I have constructed the vars file where I have defined the variables which the script should be using at runtime.

Now my problem is that I want to be able to access the ansible variables in their standard format {{my_variable}} from the bash script which I am deploying.

Is this even possible? If it isn't possible, what are your suggestions for inserting the variables into the script after its installed?

I have a feeling I am close to the answer, but scowering Ansible help files has not yielded anything yet.

The only thing I kinda figured would be to use the lineinfile module to update the shell script after its already installed, but I feel like this maybe a bit too hacky and there is probably a more elegant solution here.

I appreciate any and all answers.

Comment: Are you tried with Environment Variables? I mean setting with your bash the env vars and reading this with ansible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure – anything in /vars/main.yml is automatically available, or you can load a custom file with http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html. Then, use a template and deploy your script like this:

```
 template:
    src: script_template.j2
    dest: "path/notifiy.sh"
    mode: 700
```